# SAML Signature validation within Assertion

Tags: java, validation, saml-2.0, signature, opensaml

I have a SAML which I get from a third party. I have to validate it by using their public certificate. I have done this previously but this time the Signature is within the Assertion so my `Response.getSignature()` returns null.

I am using Java OpenSAML lib, so now even though I get the assertion and get the signature from Assertion like below, My `SignatureValidature` always errors out.

Code snippet below:

```
main()....
{
    response = (Response) parseSamlObject(samlString);
    assertion = resp.getAssertion().get(0);
    signature = assertion.getSignature(); // I get signature here
    SignatureValidator signatureValidator = new SignatureValidator(getCredential());
    signatureValidator.validate(sign); //ERRORS OUT HERE
    ....
}

private static Credential getCredential() throws org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException, FileNotFoundException {
    PublicKey key=null;

    //Get Public Key
    BasicX509Credential publicCredential = new BasicX509Credential();
    Credential verifiyingCredential = null;
    String certFileName = "myPublicCertificate.cer";
    InputStream fileStream = MyClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(certFileName);

    System.out.println("CertificateStream is Obtained from Resources......" );
    java.security.cert.CertificateFactory certificateFactory=null;
    java.security.cert.X509Certificate certificate=null;

    try {
        certificateFactory = java.security.cert.CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
        certificate = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) certificateFactory.generateCertificate(fileStream);
    } catch (CertificateException e3) {
        e3.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        fileStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e2) {
        e2.printStackTrace();
    }

    key= certificate.getPublicKey();//got publicKey here

    //Validate Public Key against Signature
    if (key != null) {
        publicCredential.setPublicKey(key);
        publicCredential.setEntityCertificate(certificate);
        verifiyingCredential = publicCredential;
    }

    return verifiyingCredential;
}
```

Errors out with the following everytime:`org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Signature did not validate against the credential's key`

Here is the SAML: https://pastebin.com/D1Rwm5Y5
Any thoughts?

Comment: Is there a way you can look into the implemenation of SignatureValidator.validate() and may be put a debug point?

Comment: First try to validare the signature using this online tool. This will tell you if it is your certificate of the java implementation that is wrong. https://www.samltool.com/validate_response.php

Comment: I am using the generic SignatureValidator at org.opensaml.xml.signature.

Comment: Do we also need to consider KeyInfo to do any validation?

Comment: I am able to see that the X509 certificate in the KeyInfo part of the SAML is same as the publicX509 certificate that was securely given to me. However `SignatureValidator.validate( assertion.getSignature)` still errors out with the same error as above.     
Any ideas of what I may have missed?

Comment: Did you ever solve this?
I am trying to solve a similar issue.

Comment: @Quintonn Yes. Response.getSignature() is null. Since the signature is within the assertion I had to do `response.getAssertions().get(0).getSignature()` to get the Signature.

Answer (score 1):

SignatureValidator is a Final class with a static method, so you don't need to create an instance

```
response = (Response) parseSamlObject(samlString);
assertion = resp.getAssertion().get(0);
signature = assertion.getSignature();

//Now you need to create a x509Credential
ByteArrayInputStream certInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(yourCert);
CertificateFactory certificateFactory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate)certificateFactory.generateCertificate(certInputStream);
BasicX509Credential credential = new BasicX509Credential(certificate);

//Now you can validate the Signature with you cert
SignatureValidator.validate(signature , credential);
```

Hope this works!! ;)